# form select not saving to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

```
<%= f.label :type %>
<%= f.select(:type, ["original","print","other"]) %>
```

I have a photos model and added a drop-down list to the form, when the
option is selected, the correct parameters are passed but it is not
saved to the database.
I've googled this and looked at the api but I'm not too sure what I'm doing.
In my photo model type is a string.

Is string the wrong field type? or anything else wrong?

Comment: try this @photo.type = params[:photo][:type];
@photo.save and see whether it is saving in the database.

Comment: put this into the form or enter it via the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `type` might be magic, it's on the wiki list of reserved words:

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords